# React.js, Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. how to fix if key is already given

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im getting the warning `Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.`. My understanding of react was that when you pass to a new component you give it the Id of a prop, which i am doing, yet im still getting this warning. In my code i have some dummy data that is used to set the state of table data i.e

```
const DumData = 
    {   id: 1,
        UserGroup:[
    {
        id: "1",
        Name: "Dax Johnson",
        AddressLine: "82 Mahu road",
        Email: 'DaxIng@Gmail.co.nz',
        ContactNumber: "02791743",
        Zip: '8801',
        Notes: 'His dog is swag',
        Animals: [
                {   id: "1",
                    PatientID: "23",
                    AnimalName: 'SwagDog',
                    Species: "Canine",
                    Breed: "Dog",
                    Gender: "Male",
                    DOB: "",
                    Vists: [{
                        id:1 ,
                        time: 'October 31st 2021'
                    },
                    {
                        id:2 ,
                        time: 'October 21st 2021'
                    }]
                },
                { id: '2',
                AnimalName: 'CoolCat',
                Species: "Feline",
                Breed: "Cat",
                Gender: "Female",
                DOB: "",
                Vists: [{
                    id:1 ,
                    time: 'March 4th 2021'
                }]
                }
                ],
    },
    {
        id: "12",
        Name: "Willam McDonald",
        AddressLine: "2 Wacky Ave",
        Email: 'WILLIAM@hotmail.co.nz',
        Zip: '8661',
        ContactNumber: "033777300",
        Notes: 'His cat is cool',
        Animals: [
              { 
              id: "1",
              PatientID: "23",
              AnimalName: "Molder",
              Species: "Feline",
              Breed: "Cat",
              Gender: "Female",
              DOB: "2008",
              Vists: [{
                id:1 ,
                time: 'February 4th 2022'
            }]
            }
            ],


      },    
      {
        id: "3",
        Name: "Oscar Issac",
        AddressLine: "2 Wacky Ave",
        Email: 'Oscar@hotmail.co.nz',
        Zip: '7041',
        ContactNumber: "0279000",
        Notes: 'His cat is cool',
        Animals: [
              { 
              id: "1",
              PatientID: "23",
              AnimalName: "Cool cat",
              Species: "Feline",
              Breed: "Cat",
              Gender: "Female",
              DOB: "2008",
              Vists: [{
                id:1 ,
                time: 'June 24th 2021'
            }]
              }
              ],
      }    ]
    
    };
```

and then later `const [tableData, settableData] = useState(DumData);`

I create a component table called Hometable where i pass it the tableData and the key id

```
<div className='Hometable-div'>
                <Hometable
                    data={tableData}
                    key={tableData.id}
                ></Hometable>
            </div>
```

and then i map the data so it is displayed in the table in the Hometable component. like so

```
function Hometable(props) {
    var OwnerName;
    var Animalname;
    var breed;

    return (
      <div className='table-container'>
          <table>
              <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th>Owner</th>
                      <th>Animal Name</th>
                      <th>Type/Breed</th>
                      <th>Vist Time</th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              {props.data.UserGroup.map((person) => (
                    OwnerName = person.Name,
                    person.Animals.map((Animal) => ( 
                        Animalname = Animal.AnimalName,
                        breed = Animal.Breed,
                        Animal.Vists.map((vist) => (
                            <tr>
                                <td>  <i class="bi bi-person-fill"></i> {OwnerName} </td>
                                <td> {Animalname}</td>
                                <td> {breed} </td>
                                <td> {vist.time} </td>
                            </tr>
                        )) 
                    )) 
                ))}

                <tr>
                  <td className='footer'> 
                      
                      </td>
                      <td className='footer'> 
                          
                      </td>
                      <td className='footer'>
                          
                          </td>
                      <td className='footer'>
                          <button className='TableButton'> Page 1</button>
                      </td>
                  </tr>
              </tbody>
          </table>

      </div>
    );
  }
  
  export default Hometable;
```

I understand i dont use the key value in `Hometable` so this might be an easy fix if anyone can help me resolve this warning?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try passing the key here in the code

```
{props.data.UserGroup.map((person) => (
                    OwnerName = person.Name,
                    person.Animals.map((Animal) => ( 
                        Animalname = Animal.AnimalName,
                        breed = Animal.Breed,
                        Animal.Vists.map((vist, index) => (
                         // or visit.id if available
                            <tr key={index}>
                                <td>  <i class="bi bi-person-fill"></i> {OwnerName} </td>
                                <td> {Animalname}</td>
                                <td> {breed} </td>
                                <td> {vist.time} </td>
                            </tr>
                        )) 
                    )) 
                ))}
```

It's recommended to use keys coming from the data source such as visit.id. Last resort should be using index. For more information you can read [here](https://robinpokorny.medium.com/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318).

Comment: Awesome thank you this worked! I dont understand why do you think you could explain?

Comment: As per the docs https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys it helps react identify which items have changed, added or removed hence the warning. The best way to pick a key is to use a string that uniquely identifies a list item among its siblings. Most often you would use IDs from your data as keys. When you don’t have stable IDs for rendered items, you may use the item index as a key as a last resort.

Comment: Using index as key is an anti-pattern , read this article https://robinpokorny.medium.com/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318

Comment: @nassimmiled Thats right its an anti-pattern thats why i suggested using visit.id in the first place and linked the documentation.

Comment: Updated a bit of details in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code :

```
function Hometable(props) {
    var OwnerName;
    var Animalname;
    var breed;

    return (
      <div className='table-container'>
          <table>
              <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th>Owner</th>
                      <th>Animal Name</th>
                      <th>Type/Breed</th>
                      <th>Vist Time</th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              {props.data.UserGroup.map((person) => (
                    OwnerName = person.Name,
                    person.Animals.map((Animal) => ( 
                        Animalname = Animal.AnimalName,
                        breed = Animal.Breed,
                        Animal.Vists.map((vist,index) => (
                            <tr  key={index}  >
                                <td>  <i class="bi bi-person-fill"></i> {OwnerName} </td>
                                <td> {Animalname}</td>
                                <td> {breed} </td>
                                <td> {vist.time} </td>
                            </tr>
                        )) 
                    )) 
                ))}

                <tr>
                  <td className='footer'> 
                      
                      </td>
                      <td className='footer'> 
                          
                      </td>
                      <td className='footer'>
                          
                          </td>
                      <td className='footer'>
                          <button className='TableButton'> Page 1</button>
                      </td>
                  </tr>
              </tbody>
          </table>

      </div>
    );
  }
  
  export default Hometable;
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion:

```
const array = [...];
...
const new_array_for_props = array.map(function(arr, index){
   <target_comp props_01={arr.props_01} key={index} />
});
```

sub component(target_comp) unnecessary uses props.key.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Every time you are in a loop, each element like those ones must define a unique key. And it is a good practice

```
- tr
- ul
- Component
- etc ...
```

ex:

```ts
Users?.map( (user: User) => (
  <tr key={user.id}>
    <td>{user.name}</td>
    <td>{user.birthdate}</td>
    <td>
      <UserEdit key={user.id} user={user}>Edit</UserEdit>
    </td>
    ...
  </tr>
));
```